# Sends get request from node to web service

Tags: node.js, html

I have a web service and a node project with a html page. I want to sends get request from my node project to my web service and in the return of web service i want to print that "hello world" on my website.

My web service.

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("myresource")
public class MyResource {


@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String hello() {

    return "Hello World";

}
}
```

My Node project:

```
var express=require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require("https");
var request=require("request");
var app=express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
res.sendfile('index.html');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("Express Started on Port 3000");
});


app.get('/this',function(req,res){

request
.get('http://localhost:8080/ConnectingToNode/webapi/myresource')
.on('response', function(response) {
 console.log(response.statusCode); // 200 
 console.log(response.headers['content-type']); 
 var a=response.toString();
  console.log(a);
  });

 });
 module.exports = app;
```

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        function This(){
 window.open("http://localhost:8080/ConnectingToNode/webapi/myresource");

        }

    </script>
 <button onclick="This()" type="button">Click Me!</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does the `var a=response.toString();` prints?
You also need to return that value from the node js router: `res.send(a)`

Comment: what the error that you are getting?  whats the value `a`?

Comment: I don't know how to get the response of hello world and shows it.

Comment: I just trying by writing response.toString(); That i get the value or not but it just return me [object Object]. How to get that hello world.